# Setting time zone offset in java 8 time versus joda time

Tags: java-8, timezone, jodatime, java-time, timezone-offset

I work for an organization in two locations. One of them is Chile, where daylight savings time is extremely unpredictable and often varies from year-to-year. We have an application that is dependent on time and up until now, have been using joda time. When the Chilean government decides to change daylight savings, we use joda code to set an offset to the default `DateTimeZone`:

```
/**
 * Updates the default time zone, i.e. the time zone which is used as local time.
 */
 private void updateDefaultTimeZone() {
    if (isEmpty(Configuration.Value.TIME_ZONE_OFFSET)) {
        // make the site's default time zone the current time zone for joda time,
        // this should always be the case for the non-Chile site, and work for the Chile site during most of the year
        DateTimeZone.setDefault(siteService.getSiteTimeZone());
    } else {
        // makes a user defined time zone the current time zone for joda time
        // this will be used when Chile is delaying or pulling forward the transition from/to daylight
        // saving time and the JVM is therefore not able to calculate the local times appropriately
        Integer offset = getInteger(Configuration.Value.TIME_ZONE_OFFSET);
        DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(offset));
    }
}
```

We're trying to transition our code base from joda time to Java 8 time, but I have really no idea the classes that are involved in doing something similar. I'm guessing perhaps `ZoneRules`, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any hints as to how to most cleanly accomplish this?

Additionally, what is the best way of converting units in Java 8 time? Say I have 24 hours and I want to convert it into days. (I ask because in this case, it seems many methods work with milliseconds and I want to work with hours, but think there must be a better built-in way to convert than to do the arithmetic by hand.)

Comment: May or may not help: https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [`java.util.TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)). Because JSR-310 `java.time.*` is integrated with the JDK, there is no need for a separate method.

(To convert units, you may find it easiest to use `TimeUnit`, but perhaps a separate more focussed question would help you there.)

Answer (score 1):

[JodaStephen has said it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634321/5772882). He’s the lead developer of both Joda-Time and java.time, so definitely the authority here. I add just some supplementary thoughts.

### Consider not relying on a default time zone

The default time zone of the JVM can be changed at any time from another part of your program and from other programs running in the same JVM. So relying on it is fragile. java.time (Java 8 time) consistently offers you the possibility of specifying time zone for all time zone sensitive operations. My habit is to use this. So my suggestion is that you store the time zone somewhere in your program where you alone control who’s tampering with it and code your date and time operations to use this stored setting and not the default time zone of the JVM.

*If* you still rely on the default: The `TimeZone` class has a bad design flaw. This would look sound to me at first sight:

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Santiago_de_Chile"));
```

It isn’t! Look at the output from

```
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

> GMT

Extremely confusing IMHO. The correct time zone ID is America/Santiago, not America/Santiago_de_Chile. So we should have expected an `IllegalArgumentException` or similar here. Instead `TimeZone` just tacitly gives us a completely wrong time zone, GMT.

Instead use:

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("America/Santiago_de_Chile")));
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: America/Santiago_de_Chile

### Time unit conversions

Like JodaStephen I routinely use `TimeUnit` for time unit conversions, but I try to remember to think twice before doing so.

```
    System.out.println(TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(24));
    System.out.println(TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(400_000_000_000_000_000L));
```

> ```
> 1
> 9223372036854775807
> ```

It looks right, doesn’t it? It isn’t either! For two reasons:

1. A day is not always 24 hours. When Chile goes from standard time to summer time (DST) or vice versa, a day is 23 or 25 hours.
2. The conversion doesn’t report `long` overflow. The latter conversion overflows. `TimeUnit` tacitly gives us the closest value that can fit in a `long`, in this case the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

When you know what you are doing and you know your conversions don’t overflow, you may use it. I also do most of my `int` math without checking for overflow. java.time offers a nice converstion that does check for overflow:

```
    System.out.println(Duration.ofDays(400_000_000_000_000_000L).toHours());
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow

I even find this code a bit more readable than the `TimeUnit` code.